# Javascript find and delete by value in multidimensional object/array

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

What I basically need is to find item in multidimensional array and delete only it. The problem is that there are more then one same object keys in this.

array example (copied from console):

```
gameDetails.betsArray = [{
    '1.02': {
        userDetails: {
            socketID: '/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA',
            userID: 1
        },
        trigger: 110,
        parseD: 1.02
    }
}, {
    '1.02': {
        userDetails: {
            socketID: '/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA',
            userID: 5
        },
        trigger: 881,
        parseD: 1.02
    }
}]
```

**how array is being made**

```
gameDetails.betsArray[validator.toFloat(betDetails.breakAt)] = {
    userDetails: {
        socketID: socketID,
        userID: connectedUsers[socketID].id
    },
    betAmount: validator.toInt(betDetails.amount),
    breakAt: validator.toFloat(betDetails.breakAt)
};
```

and I want to find object by `key` which is 1.02 and `object.userDetails.userID = 5`

what I have tried and it didn't worked for me:

```
gameDetails.betsArray.map(function (details, key) {
    if (details.userDetails.userID == connectedUsers[socketID].id &&
        details.trigger == validator.toFloat(betDetails.trigger)) {
        delete gameDetails.betsArray[key];
    }
});
```

how is it possible to make? In the final step I want to remove data from the array of found object.

Comment: How about `Array#filter` ?

Comment: delete in situ, or filtering with out the specified?

Comment: @Rayon tried this also, didn't worked or I don't know how to use it in this situation

Comment: You can't create objects into arrays like that

Comment: im not creating it like that, its just an example of what I have (printed array value)

Comment: Sorry, your syntax isn't correct. `['a': ...]` is not a valid array (you can't use `:` in an array. But, even if you used an Object, so `{ '1.02': { ... }, '1.02': { ... } }`, that still wouldn't work because you have two keys with the value `1.02`. Can you fix this typo first?

Comment: I dont think it is a valid structure  **'1.02':** and so is throwing _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :_

Comment: no, the syntax is correct I've just copied it from console after debugging it on it.. anyways edited with formula of creating array

Comment: Just copy/paste "copied from console" code into the console.

Comment: @NerisUska, change the way your Array is built to `gameDetails.betsArray.push({ ... })`. otherwise it simply won't work the way you're trying it. Now you can use `filter()` to get an Array of all the nodes that match your criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Attempt of a solution with a valid data structure and [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "1.02": {
>             "userDetails": {
>                 "socketID": "/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA",
>                 "userID": 1
>             },
>             "trigger": 110,
>             "parseD": 1.02
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         "1.02": {
>             "userDetails": {
>                 "socketID": "/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA",
>                 "userID": 5
>             },
>             "trigger": 881,
>             "parseD": 1.02
>         }
>     }
> ]
> ```

```js
var data = [{ '1.02': { userDetails: { socketID: '/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA', userID: 1 }, trigger: 110, parseD: 1.02 } }, { '1.02': { userDetails: { socketID: '/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA', userID: 5 }, trigger: 881, parseD: 1.02 } }];

data = data.filter(function (a) {
    return !a['1.02'] || a['1.02'].userDetails.userID !== 5;
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change your data structure to valid javascript data for example array of objects like this and then you can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var obj = [{
  '1.02': {
    userDetails: {
      socketID: '/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA',
      userID: 1
    },
    trigger: 110,
    parseD: 1.02
  }
}, {
  '1.02': {
    userDetails: {
      socketID: '/#32EZlk6tW03tNgnOAAAA',
      userID: 5
    },
    trigger: 881,
    parseD: 1.02
  }
}]

var result = obj.filter(function(e) {
  if (e['1.02'] && e['1.02'].userDetails.userID == 5) return e;
});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: its not work like that because the key does not stand like this. all the array is made like `[key={}, key={}]` and not like `[{key: {}}, {key: {}}]`

Comment: That is not valid js data, it won't work as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1003/

Comment: i have typed a method how array is being made in my question and it works, just your syntax is a little bit different from my method

Comment: Then the second value will overwrite the first one. One key can only contain one value, although this value may be an Array; but that's not the case here.